# Refresh ajax datatable

Tags: datatable

I'm running the ajax datatable in a JavaScript function that is called from the onblur of input for parameters I send two pieces of information that go into the url ajax and depending on these parameters, different data will be returned.

```
function abrirModal(idLista,value)
{
var lastIdx = null;
var table = window.parent.$("#tlistaselect").DataTable( {
    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "aProcessing": true,
    "aServerSide": true,
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "retrieve": true,
    "stateSave":true,
    "ajax": ip+"/datosListaSelect?idLista="+idLista+"&condicion="+value,
    ...................
}
```

When I run for the first time Ajax, brings the data you need depending on the values of the parameters but when I try to run again not run the ajax, I just redisplay the data had already consulted earlier.

How I can do to make the ajax to run again when I call the function again with the onblur?

Comment: Are you sure the function gets called again? Put some logging in there

Comment: Of course. $divpropiedades .='<input id="'.$nombremetadato["idDocumentoPropiedad"].'" '.$eventoblur.'  name="'.$nombremetadato["idDocumentoPropiedad"].'" class="form-control '.$clase.'" type="text" placeholder="Seleccione '.str_replace('_', ' ', $nombremetadato["tituloDocumentoPropiedad"]).'" onblur="abrirModal('.$idLista.',this.value);">'; 
Each input with these characteristics must execute the function again

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more tag in DataTable section: 
"destroy": true

I think it will work!